# Error handling when SWbemObjectSet has no instances

Tags: vbscript, wmi

According to [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406382.aspx#H21), I can use the `.Count` property to determine if a WMI query has results. For their example, they count the number of tape drives installed:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\ROOT\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( "SELECT * FROM Win32_TapeDrive")
wscript.stdout.writeline "Error: " & Err.Description
wscript.stdout.writeline "Count: " &  colItems.count
wscript.stdout.writeline "Error: " & Err.Description
```

Output:

```
'Output (as expected per the TechNet article)
Error:
Count: 0
Error:
```

What I'm trying to do is inventory monitors though. The following code works great when a monitor is attached, but it crashes when there isn't one:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\ROOT\WMI")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( "SELECT * FROM WMIMonitorID")
wscript.stdout.writeline "Error: " & Err.Description
wscript.stdout.writeline "Count: " &  colItems.count
wscript.stdout.writeline "Error: " & Err.Description
```

Output:

```
'Output (not as expected)
Error: 
temp_script.vbs(5, 1) SWbemObjectSet: Not supported
'The error number is 0x8004100C
```

Using

```
Set colItems =  GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\ROOT\WMI").InstancesOf("WmiMonitorID")
```

gives the same result, and as you can see, no error is thrown until I try to access a property of colItems. I can work around this issue by using `On Error Resume Next`, but this code is part of a larger project so I'd rather not ignore every error.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\ROOT\WMI")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( "SELECT * FROM WMIMonitorID")
wscript.stdout.writeline "Error: " & Err.Description
wscript.stdout.writeline "Count: " &  colItems.count
wscript.stdout.writeline "Error: " & Err.Description
```

Output:

```
'Output (as expected)
Error:
Error: Not supported
```

The machine I'm testing this against is a Windows 2012 R2 server with no tape drives and no attached monitors. Is there a way for me to test an SWbemObjectSet object for "stuff" without it throwing an error? Or is there a way I can handle this error without ignoring every error? I could only find two SO posts ([Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851511/vbscript-swbemobjectset-error-8004100c)  and [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920059/vbscript-how-to-inspect-validity-of-swbemobjectset)) that deal with this. The one that places `.Count` in a function seems workable, but is there any other way to deal with no instances of a class?

Comment: I'd say the answer to post 2 is the way to go. I'd probably be more specific about the error number, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript: how to inspect validity of SWbemObjectSet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920059/vbscript-how-to-inspect-validity-of-swbemobjectset)

Comment: You don't have to *"ignore every error"* just place `On Error Resume Next` at the start and `On Error Goto 0` at the end of the code you want to manually check for an error.

Comment: What about using the [`WbemFlagEnum` flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393980(v=vs.85).aspx) `wbemFlagForwardOnly` does that alter the behaviour of `ExecQuery()`?

Comment: The beauty of post 2 approch is you don't have to handle the `On Error Resume Next` with `On Error Goto 0` as it only exists for the scope of the function everything else outside that scope will still trigger errors without skipping.

Comment: @Lankymart - Changing the flags does not affect the results. Plus, as the documentation states, "the SWbemObjectSet.Count method cannot be used since it requires rewinding the enumerator", so setting the ForwardOnly flag would cause count to crash. Also, this is essentially the same root problem I linked in my post and you've flagged as a duplicate, but the other is dealing with non-existent classes while mine deals with classes that exist but are empty (thus the different error numbers being returned).

Comment: @Tim fair comment, I just wondered if `wbemFlagForwardOnly` behaved differently and while it does it doesn't really help you, worth a try at least. However while your problem is *slightly* different the actual solution is more a less the same which is why I flagged it, that is no indication of the quality of your question though.